# User defined dictionary in lingo3g for Elasticsearch wrt label/word/synonym

Tags: elasticsearch, carrot2

While browsing the lingo3g manual I came across with http://download.carrotsearch.com/lingo3g/1.9.0/manual/#chapter.lexical-resources

Which states that we can customize the name of the label as per pre defined Word/Label dictionary.

So I have some doubts on basis of that:

1. Where exactly these files have to be kept in ES (either in ES/config
   or somewhere else)
2. Is it like if we are using these dictionaries so default dictionary
   with POS will not work in clustering the label?
3. If we use these particular dictionaries so the label name after
   clustering will be formed on basis of this only or some other logic
   is also there?
4. How I can check the built-in word databases wrt ES for clustering,
   is word-dictionary.en.xml is the built-in databse file for ES?
   Source: http://download.carrotsearch.com/lingo3g/manual/#section.attribute.use-built-in-word-database-for-label-filtering

Answer (score 0):

Answered on ES mailing list. Please do not cross-post.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elasticsearch/vzUcKxDMFoQ/4AFSj0yCEYUJ